# Understanding logging error while running `mvn clean install`

Tags: java, maven, logging, path, virtual-machine

I'm using maven to build an application using the command `mvn clean install`.

I recently downloaded the Java 8 JDK, reset my JAVA_HOME path variable like this in ~/.bash_profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

and did a sanity check by running `java -version` which has the correct version (1.8.0_191).

However, the maven command produces the following error:

[image]

When I opened up the suggested log in surefire-reports to see what was going on, this is what its contents were:

```
# Created at 2018-12-17T11:53:50.586
Unrecognized VM option 'UseSplitVerifier'

# Created at 2018-12-17T11:53:50.586
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

# Created at 2018-12-17T11:53:50.586
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

**UPDATE** (to address comments): When I include the flag to skip tests, this is the error output:

[image]

Comment: First building only needs `mvn clean verify`. An `mvn clean install` is not needed. Furthermore you have test failures. Do you use junit-jupiter?

Comment: I ran the build with the flag enabled to skip tests and updated my original post to show the new error.

Comment: Update the plugin...

Comment: Running `mvn compile` before running `mvn clean install` remedied the issue. I honestly don't know why.